# Is it posible to run my php files in cordova?

Tags: php

I am currently developing an android application using ionic framework, and the only thing I know is that HTML, Javascript, and Jquery can run in an ionic framework. How do I run my PHP file using the ionic framework?

Comment: Hi Jmark, Welcome to SO. Do check [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you could not run php files in Cordova. If you want to handle your data and requests with PHP then better way set any PHP framework as backend and use API calls to communicate with it.

One lightweight and good secured PHP framework is CODEIGNITER. You can use [rest api](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814) of codeignitor to communicate with your ionic framework. You just get to know how to use API in ionic framework.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your idea.

Comment: Most welcome:) You can accept answer and make upvote as well.